# Regex to match SCSS selector with possible nesting

Tags: javascript, css, regex

So I need a javascript regex to match a CSS/LESS/SCSS selector and its associated styles, i.e. all of

```
.selector {
  height: 200px;
}
```

Or

```
.selector {
    height: 200px;

    .nestedselector {
      width: 200px;
    }
}
```

I currently have

```
[\.|#]selector\s*{([\s*\w-]*:[\s*\w]*;)*\s*}
```

but it doesn't handle nested cases, as trying to incorporate them so far has caused me to match my entire stylesheet.

Comment: regexp is not very good for nested arbitrary syntax, a parse is a better bet.

Comment: *I need a javascript regex to match a CSS/LESS/SSS selector*. Why do you need such a regex?

Comment: Hmm yeah @dandavis that makes sense I guess I can just go with a parser. I need such a regex for a texteditor plugin that needs to display the associated styles for any given DOM element.